# OnTriggerEnter not working when placed inside Update()

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics

I'm making a scanner that scans the "world" (like a 10 x 10 space), and I'm trying to sense a `GameObject` called pointer.

They both have colliders, they both have triggers, and the scanner has a rigidbody. I have tried the `OnTriggerEnter` method outside of the update, and it worked, but as soon as I put it inside of `Update`, it breaks.

I don't have to worry about being specific on what the scanner is detecting, because those two are the only ones with a collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scan : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int worldHeight;
    public int worldWidth;    

    public bool sensed;

    public bool spaceBar = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && spaceBar == false)
        {
            spaceBar = true;

            sensed = false;

            //brings scanner to top left corner of world
            transform.position = new Vector3(worldWidth / 2 * -0.64f + 0.32f, worldHeight / 2 * 0.64f + 0.32f, -1);

            for (int sizey = 0; sizey < worldHeight; sizey++)
            {
                if (sensed == false)
                {
                    //shifts scanner down
                    transform.position = new Vector3(worldWidth / 2 * -0.64f - 0.32f, transform.position.y, -1);
                    transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0.64f);

                    for (int sizex = 0; sizex < worldWidth; sizex++)
                    {
                        if (sensed == false)
                        {
                            //shifts scanner right
                            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0.64f, 0);

                            void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D grid)
                            {
                                //not working ;-;
                                sensed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            spaceBar = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity will call your `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter` callback only if it is a member of your type, not a local method buried in another function.

It looks like you might want to use a physics query here instead, like [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html). This lets you check for overlapping physics objects in a particular volume of space on demand, using layers or trigger query controls to filter what kinds of objects should be detected.